# No operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++, redefinition

Please.help me solving this strange compile error. I am redefining the operator << for
my class Student,but at "s.name" this error appears. The variable s.name is a string...

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream& output, Student &s)
{
output<<"\nIme: "<<s.name<<"\nFakulteten nomer: "<<s.fakn<<"\nSreden uspeh: "<<s.srus<<endl;
return output;
}
```

Here is the variables definition:

```
class Student{

private:
string name;
string fakn;
Date date;
double srus;
```

The redefinition function is defined as friend in my class:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Student &s);
```

Comment: are you sure it is a string? can we see the definition?

Comment: I put the variables definition code.

Comment: with your latest updates, I think we need a SSCCE. Try making a small but complete version of your code which shows the error on a service like codepad.org

Comment: To be clear, I cannot reproduce the error: http://codepad.org/vaDrCIn3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 functions:

```
string Student::getAsString()const{
 ostringstream oss;
 oss << "Student name: " << name  << "   "  << fakn << "   " << srus; //etc
 return oss.str();
}


ostream & operator<<( ostream & exit, const Student & ob){
  return exit << "Exit:" << ob.getAsString() << endl;
}
```

And dont forget to add the respective libraries:

```
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iostream>
```

Comment: you do not need to create the "getAsString" or similar function if the << is marked as a friend, as the OP indicated.

Comment: The problem was solved with adding #include <string>.

Answer (score 5):

`Student::name` is private so it can't be accessed by `operator<<`. You need to make variable public, or create public getter for it, or make `operator<<` friend of `Student` class so that it can access it's private members.